# POW is showing previous gemset path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rack-pow

So I am having some issues with POW loading my rails application. When I try to visit the http://app.dev url i get the following error:

```
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find minitest-5.4.1 in any of the sources
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
```

I updated my ruby to 2.1.2 and created a new gemset for this app, and set RVM to use this gemset in the application folder. However, pow is still trying to use the default 2.0.0@global gemset?

According to POW/RVM documentations, I have tried placing a .powrc file in the application root, but i still cannot get pow to use the proper gemset.

I can access the app file in the rails console, no errors. I think its strictly POW having the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up restarting the POW server, and it resolved the issue

```
touch ~/.pow/restart.txt
```